# BigCommerce API Syntax Error

Tags: php, api, bigcommerce

I have just installed the bigcommerce api onto my server. And when I attempt to hit the template, I receive the following syntax error. Is there a specific setting that must be set for this to work correctly?

http://firstdynamic.com/BigCommerce/bigcommerce.php

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/fdw/public_html/BigCommerce/bigcommerce.php on line 2

This is line 2:

```
namespace Bigcommerce\Api {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue resolved -

The server was running PHP version 5.2. When atleast php version 5.3 was required.